# Problem positionning buttons under a google map fragment in a bottom navigation layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have an app that has bottom navigation with three tabs. On one of the screen of the app I have a Google Map fragment. I wish to show three buttons under the map fragment and above the bottom navigation for this screen only.

When I'm in the designer for this specific fragment, it shows what I want (here the grey "fragment" is in fact the Google Map fragment)

You can download the code from github : https://github.com/guyprovost/BottomBug/tree/master

[image: Designer view for the Google Map fragment]

But when I run the app, this is what I got:

[image: Runtime]

I was aiming at this end result, (sorry for the poorly draw explanation of the desired result, but you get the idea!)

[image: Desired result]

Here's the fragment layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/controlBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/primaryDark"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testbutton1"
        android:text="One"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testbutton2"
        android:text="Two" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".40" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testbutton3"
        android:text="Three" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the main activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="16dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the bottom navigation menu xml file content :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_map"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:title="@string/tab1_title"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_history"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
        android:title="@string/tab2_title"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/tab3_title"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

I looks like that either the map fragment height can't be properly manipulated at runtime or it can't be used like that in a bottom navigation layout... Or that I goofed miserably somewhere, which is higly possible.

Any clues ?

Comment: Try managing the MapFragment by code instead of xml

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your hint, but eager to learn...

Comment: Possible error could be that you are using weights in  fragment's layout but not assigning weight to `LinearLayout` accordingly. Do that and please use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`

Comment: in main activity layout try and give 56dp bottom margin to framelayout.

Comment: try to put this line in your bottomNavigationXml :
`android:background="@android:color/transparent"` it'll make your bottom navigation transparent and you can see if your three buttons are actually behind bottom navigation or not.

Comment: @Faisal I did try that and it does work as I said in another comment, layout modifications I do in the activity layout are honored, but not those in the fragment's layout. If I do add a bottom margin to the activity layout, I see the margin, but not the buttons that are in the fragment's layout, it's like no matter what I do, the map will "fill" the space of frame reserved for it it the activity layout. Must be something I dont get! Plus, If I do that in the activity layout, every fragments will have to deal with it too!

Comment: if its still not working, Can you put your project of git. I'll fix it for you then.

Comment: @Faisal, this project is a Xamarin.Droid Project, I could sent a bare minimum code that shows the problem, are you ok with Xamarin ?

Comment: @Faisal, here's the repo's adress : https://github.com/guyprovost/BottomBug/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your query properly then let me give you a solution that can you use relative layout instead of linear layout like below and also let me tell you that i'm understanding that you need your navigation view in main activity as well you need three buttons on top of navigation view and on top of that you need map fragment. right? so here is the solution:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/controlBar"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/controlBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/primaryDark"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/testbutton1"
            android:text="One"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".30"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/testbutton2"
            android:text="Two" 
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".40" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/testbutton3"
            android:text="Three" 
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".30" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey there! Appreciated a lot your answer, but it end's up as the exact same result. I dont see the buttons, the only difference is in the designer rendering. But the end results stays exactly the same. I dont know if I understand you correctly, but I need the three buttons only in the map fragment one. This is one it is defined in the fragment layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this i checked it on my phone and it's working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/controlBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testbutton1"
        android:text="One"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testbutton2"
        android:text="Two"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".40" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testbutton3"
        android:text="Three"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="16dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This is my output in emulator]

Comment: Thanks for your input, but after copy/paste of your axml, I still have the exact same output. Did you use the same activity layout as mine ? Like said, the problem seems to come from the fact that the app uses a bottom navigation paradigm. Pretty sure that the same code in an activity layout works jsut fine, but not when integrated with a FrameLayout... Maybe that this is the problem ?

Comment: let me check once again

Comment: @guyprovost i made same app working fine for me .check by running on phone not in emulator

Comment: Ok, I sure will. I did the tests on an emulator. Seems to me that every layout trick I do on the fragment layout file are not rendered, just what's outside of this file is! I'll test this afternoon, thanks for your time!

Comment: Just did the test with a real device and still have the exact same output! Are you sure you use the activity layout (main) ? I'm inflating the map fragment in the main activity using a fragment manager. I've noticed that anything I try to do layout wise in the fragment itself is ignored, all it does is stretch to fill the parent! I appreciate the time you invest in this problem!

Comment: @guyprovost may be it's studio problem. try by making a new project

Comment: I see that what you did achieve what I'm aimig at, but this is not a map fragment in there. I'll try to troubleshoot by taking out the mapfragment and using test fragment isntead of map.... We'll see.  Can you show me the activity layout you used ?

Comment: @guyprovost ok, i used same as yours, i delete the api key so that it is show like that in image

Comment: I set a github repo with my code using your update. If you want to take a look : https://github.com/guyprovost/BottomBug/tree/master